# google api service account Client_Secret

Tags: google-calendar-api

Ok, this is probably something obvious.  I have obtained a service account Client ID on my Google Developer console.  So...I have a client ID.  All the test code I see also requires a Client_Secret.  I can't for the life of me find out where to obtain or set the Client_Secret.  What is it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Service account, in Google Developpers Console there is a section to generate a key.
Have a look at this pic.
[image]

Comment: If this helped you solve your problem please accept the answer to close the thread

Comment: This does not answer the OP question. Where is "Client Secret" in your screenshot?

Comment: This is an old issue I hope the user has found the solution by now. Anyway, from what I remember you just have to click on "Generate a new key" in upper right corner of my screenshot. At least, this is how I did it about two years ago.